# CVE-2016-3093 proof of concept

Tags: security, struts2

How do I confirm whether my Struts application is affected by CVE-2016-3093?

Could not find any useful information on the [Struts forum link](http://struts.apache.org/docs/s2-034.html) . Currently I am using Struts 2.3.24.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: From the Security Bulletins link: *This issue was resolved by publising new OGNL version, any Struts version which at least is using OGNL 3.0.12 is safe.*